# iOS Request Server in App Delegate

Tags: iphone, request

Is it a good practice to request data from server in method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do an async call, sure! (And doing network calls in any other way than async on the iPhone is almost always wrong.)